# AlertDialog does not display when used with a button

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

I would like to display an alert when my "save" button is pressed if the textview fields are left blank.  However, I can not get an AlertDialog box to appear within my save button.  The same code works for the AlertDialog if it is outside of the button.  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.  I read several similar questions for none of the solutions are solving my problem.  My code is below:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
```

...

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

...

```
Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.data_save);

new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)  
        .setMessage("This is a test")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }})
         .show();

saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);   
                  builder.setMessage("This is a test 2 ")
                         .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                 dialog.cancel();
                             }
                          })
                          .show();


        }                               
        );
```

Comment: Are you getting some sort of exception?

Comment: I did not get a post in my email for your response.  I apologize for not responding sooner.  To answer your question, I do not get any exceptions.  The alert dialog never appears when I click the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine for me. If you are getting any sort of exception post it. Try Clean-ing the project and try again.

Comment: No exception is thrown.  The alert simply does not generate when I click on my button.  I even traced it in debug and it passes all of the code but I do not see the box.

Comment: I am doing it now.  I am closing eclipse and my emulator before I re-test.

Comment: I should probably make sure that I am clear on what you mean by cleaning the project.  I am re-building the project and closing the emulator.  Is there something else that I should do to get the project "clean"?

Comment: Go to `Project -> Clean select your project and hit the OK`

Comment: Thank you. I cleaned the project but it still doesn't work.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm sorry. The snippet of code you've posted worked for me flawlessly.

Comment: No problem, you just helped me anyway.  Since it was working for you, I tried something different.  I let the code fall through to the end of the "button" code and the alert does appear.  However, I am still unclear on why it would not display the alert as soon as it hits the code.  Because of this strangeness, it gets tripped up with an error four text fields down on my view.  Thanks again

Comment: I erased the code where you planning to hit it directly, just used the one inside the click listener...